# Dynamic css values without scss

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors, less

Is it possible to create a dynamic css class (with no SCSS)?

For an exmaple:

```
.background-[color]{
  background-color : [color]
}
```

Comment: No, not in a way like your pseudo code suggests. [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr()) would basically allow something not too far off, based on values of attributes of the element, but browser support for that is currently rather poor.

Comment: Are you using a front-end framework? This depends on that a lot as to where a potential answer could lie.

Comment: @MichaelC no, pure css

Comment: @CBroe Thank you, i'll check if it fits my needs

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in that way:

`var` in css with attr `style` to send your wanted style

```css
div{
color:var(--color);
}
```

```html
<div style="--color:red">try mr</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to wtire css classes and not use style. Is there an option to that similary with class name?